# What is the purpose of OpenDistro/Elasticsearch cluster permission cluster:monitor/main?

Tags: elasticsearch, serilog, elasticsearch-opendistro

On the *Permissions* page of OpenDistro, [Permissions](https://opendistro.github.io/for-elasticsearch-docs/docs/security/access-control/permissions/), the cluster permission **cluster:monitor/main** is mentioned. However, I've been unable to find any documentation or information regarding what this permission actually gives access to.

The minimum amount of info I've been able to find is that it gives access to the root endpoint of the *cluster* endpoint, and that the endpoint can display things like cluster version and other general stats. At least according to the following post: [Discuss Elasticsearch](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/security-exception-action-cluster-monitor-main-is-unauthorized-for-user-p595200/107756/2).

The reason that I'm interested in that specific permission is that I'm experiencing issues when using *Serilog* to log to multiple nodes in a cluster using C#. The application that logs using Serilog receives Unauthorized exceptions, with the Elasticsearch cluster displaying the message: *"No permissions for [cluster:monitor/main]"*. Granting the internal Elasticsearch user, which is used with Serilog, the *cluster:monitor/main* permission fixes the issue. But I don't know what the permission opens up for, or why the user doing logging actually even needs that permission to begin with.

So the question boils down to:

*What does the permission cluster:monitor/main do, and why is it required for the user doing the logging when using a multi-node cluster with Serilog?*

Answer (score 0):

You are right when saying "it gives access to the root endpoint of the cluster endpoint, and that the endpoint can display things like cluster version and other general stats".

To further clarify what the action is performing, look at the logic for this action:
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/7.9/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/action/main/TransportMainAction.java#L49

It is merely getting the cluster state.

`ClusterState clusterState = clusterService.state();`